# 3d-force-graph bidirectional links

Tags: javascript, graph

I have the following graph using : https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph librabry

```js
const gData = {
    nodes: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    links: [
        { source: 2, target: 3 },
        { source: 3, target: 2 }]
};

const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
    (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
    .graphData(gData)
    .linkDirectionalArrowLength(3.5)
    .linkDirectionalArrowRelPos(1)
    .linkCurvature(0.2);
```

As you can see I have 2 nodes and 2 links.

Those links are directional (I mean that visually they are represented with an arrow from source to target)

The problem is when we are going through big graphs, those directional links pose a problem.

I want to make them bidirectional. If there is a link from A to B and B to A (like in the example) I want one link but with 2 tips on the arrow.

I know that if I go for

```js
.linkCurvature(0);
```

visually there will be only one link but actually, there are still 2 on each other.

Here is a codepen:
[Graph](https://codepen.io/l-o-pard/pen/abMjoLE)

Comment: You should probably state what graphing library you’re using.

Comment: 3d-force-graph it's on the title

Comment: I mean it’s directed graph, but… maybe with an ArrowHelper? You’d have to extend/fork/? the library, or the one it uses, to alter its behavior—it doesn’t look like it’s customizable in this way at the top level. Maybe you can add the helpers outside of the library; idk.